# Call Method based on Type of Parameter

Tags: c#

I have an object that can be of type `AudioRequest` or `VideoRequest`. Both classes inherit from `Request`. I have this class:

```
public static DoThings
{
    public static void HandleRequest(AudioRequest r)
    {
        // Do things.
    }

    public static void HandleRequest(VideoRequest r)
    {
        // Do things.
    }
}
```

I want to be able to call `DoThings.HandleRequest(r)` where `r` can be either a `VideoRequest` or `AudioRequest` and have it call the correct one. Is that possible? I have no control over the `*Request` classes, so I can't do anything to them. I do have control of the `DoThings` class and the code that calls `HandleRequest`. This is the code that calls it, it is WebAPI:

```
public Response Post(Request input)
{
    return DoThings.HandleRequest(input);
}
```

The code above gives the error `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Request' to 'AudioRequest'`.

The original code that I was cleaning up had this:

```
if (input.GetType() == typeof(AudioRequest))
{
    var audioRequest = (AudioRequest)input;
    DoThings.HandleRequest(audioRequest);
}
else if (input.GetType() == typeof(VideoRequest))
{
    var videoRequest = (VideoRequest)input;
    DoThings.HandleRequest(videoRequest);
}
```

But I figured there was a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: One overload should have a parameter of type AudioRequest, and the other with a parameter of type VideoRequest.

Comment: Surely that's a typo that you have two identical functions? One of them should accept a `VideoRequest` argument. Otherwise you'd get a compile error.

Comment: Oops, my mistake. Yes, the second one should be VideoRequest.

Comment: You need to show us more of the code that contains `DoThings.HandleRequest(r)` that is the important piece of information.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184042/how-to-call-a-function-dynamically-based-on-an-object-type

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on the information you've provided so far, your question appears to be a duplicate of [How to call a function dynamically based on an object type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1184042). I agree with the answer, that the fact that you want to do this suggests you should rethink the design. But, you can use `dynamic` to accomplish what you want.

Here's a simple console program that demonstrates the basic idea:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A b = new B(), c = new C();

        M(b);
        M(c);
    }

    static void M(A a)
    {
        WriteLine("M(A)");
        M((dynamic)a);
    }

    static void M(B b)
    {
        WriteLine("M(B)");
    }

    static void M(C c)
    {
        WriteLine("M(C)");
    }
}

class A { }
class B : A { }
class C : A { }
```

The output is:

```
M(A)
M(B)
M(A)
M(C)
```

As you can see, in each case the `M(A)` method is called first, and then the appropriate `M(B)` or `M(C)` overload is called from `M(A)`.

In your own example, this could look something like this:

```
public static DoThings
{
    public static void HandleRequest(Request r)
    {
        // Dynamic dispatch to actual method:
        HandleRequest((dynamic)r);
    }

    public static void HandleRequest(AudioRequest r)
    {
        // Do things.
    }

    public static void HandleRequest(VideoRequest r)
    {
        // Do things.
    }
}
```

Note that `dynamic` does incur a run-time cost, particularly the first time a method is called with a given run-time type. But depending on the frequency and complexity of these "requests", using `dynamic` could be the cleanest way out of the current situation.

Comment: This does seem like the cleanest way. I don't think the overhead is relevant in my case, it's a pretty low volume service. I'll either do the `dynamic` thing, or a series of if/else statements. Thanks!

Comment: What about this suggests I should rethink the design? Are there alternative approaches that are perceived as better design?

Comment: @shieldgenerator7: I don't know what your design is, so it's difficult to comment. But in the context of the original question here, the fact is that using `dynamic` is usually not the correct approach. The feature was introduced to C# to support scenarios where it's impossible or impractical to provide compile-time/static typing for objects, COM-interop being the main example of this. If one is using `dynamic` in a pure-C# environment, there are usually much better, more idiomatic, more type-safe ways to approach the design.

Answer (score 0):

C# will call the appropriate function that matches the arguments and their types. 
That being said, both of your functions accept AudioRequest, I believe one of those should accept a VideoRequest.

```
public static DoThings
{
    public static void HandleRequest(AudioRequest r)
    {
        // Do things.
    }

    public static void HandleRequest(VideoRequest r)
    {
        // Do things.
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that at the call site, the compile-time type of the parameter is in fact different for different types of objects? Or even anything _other_ than `Request`, the base class?

Comment: @PeterDuniho it will never be anything other than an AudioRequest or a VideoRequest, it won't even be the base Request.

Comment: @JoshuaWaring I tried that, it doesn't decide, gives me an error (just put the error in the question above).

Comment: @vkapadia: _"it will never be anything other than an AudioRequest or a VideoRequest"_ -- you are missing the point. For the right overload to be selected, the type _must_ be known at _compile_ time. From the error message you describe, it is as I suspected: this is not the case, indeed all you know about the object is that it has the type `Request`, and this answer will not address your scenario.

Answer (score -3):

If for some reason you must have two different functions that take only AudioRequest you can differentiate between two function with an extra parameter

```
    public static class DoThings
{
    public static void HandleRequest(AudioRequest r)
    {
        // Do things.
    }

    public static void HandleRequest(AudioRequest r, bool UseAlternativeMethod)
    {
        // Do other things.
    }
}
```

Simply having a second parameter will call the second method regardless of it's value.

This isn't a best practices solution as you'd rather discriminate between them by accurately renaming the method name to be accurate but in practice you don't always have a choice.

Comment: The problem with this is that the desired functionality I'm assuming is that he can call the function and have the interpreter determine which function to call, instead of manually figuring it out.

Otherwise, the solution could be as simple as using a different function name.

Comment: It was my mistake. The second HandleRequest should take in a VideoRequest object.